# Need a concise term to denote "request to borrow"

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, expression-choice

The context is that I am developing a web application, in which there's the concept of allowing one party to request to borrow items from another party. Up to this point, we have been calling it "borrowing request". I want to call it "borrow request" because it's short, but then it sounds a bit awkward to my ears.

Q: Can I call it "borrow request"? If not, is "borrowing request" as concise as it gets? Thanks.

Comment: I think 'use request' may be an alternative: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=use+request%2C+borrowing+request&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuse%20request%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cborrowing%20request%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Thank you, @Josh61, that's something that we have never thought about. We will consider it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Borrow request" is not correct, but in the context of a game people will understand what you mean.

"Loan request" is an alternative that is shorter than "borrowing request" and more common [books.google.com/ngrams...](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=use%20request%2Cborrowing%20request%2C%20loan%20request&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cuse%20request%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cborrowing%20request%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cloan%20request%3B%2Cc0)

Although "loan" is often used when talking about money, it is not restricted to that context.

If you want to borrow a book and your local library does not have it, you put in an [Interlibrary loan request](http://www.illawarra.tafensw.edu.au/support-for-students/library-and-information-services/campus-libraries/contact-your-library/interlibrary-loan-request).